# Convert linear programming problem into its standard form

Tags: linear-programming

all,

I met a question that, the cost function of the linear programming problem is a function with absolute value. Here is the problem:

min 3x1+|6x2+3|
st.
|x1+4|+|2x2|<=3

How can I deal with it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace $|6 x_2 + 3|$ by a new variable $x_3$ with $x_3 \le 6 x_2 + 3$ and 
$x_3 \le -(6 x_2 + 3)$.  Similarly your constraint becomes four constraints 
$\pm (x_1 + 4) \pm (2 x_2) \le 3$.